# Force height on an empty floating div with background image

Tags: html, css

I have a container with 2 floating divs. The right div is **empty** and needs to simply show a centered background image. Yet, the right div has no height (even if I set it to `height: 100%;`), which prevents the background image to be shown.

**How do I force the height of the right div to be equal to the parent container?** Keep in mind that the parent's height is dynamic.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fl">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

  <!--Background image should appear below, in the empty div-->
  <div class="fl bg-img"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fl {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.bg-img {
  background: url('https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/photos/000/755/75552.ngsversion.1422285553360.adapt.1900.1.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/mL1qppsu/

Answer (score 2):

Just make use of flexbox on the parent wrapper container.
Set the background-size to 100% if you want it to change with respect to wrapper (you can also use `cover` or `contain`), it will accomodate the div dynamically according to the parent container's height.

Using `contain` here is more appropriate since it won't let your image be cropped and change its dimensions dynamically.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display:flex;
}

.fl {
  width: 50%;
}

.bg-img {
  background: url('https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/photos/000/755/75552.ngsversion.1422285553360.adapt.1900.1.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size:contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fl">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="fl bg-img"></div>
</div>

.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `height` for the  `.wrapper` element, which is the parent element of `.bg-img`. A percentage height always needs a reference height in the parent element. And if you only use percentage values for heights, every ancestor up to `body` and `html` (or up to an element with a fixed height) has to be set to a percentage value, usually 100%.

In your fiddle this would look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vfaj42fh/1/

Comment: What if the parent has dynamic height?

Comment: I extended my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the **Flexbox**:

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
}

.fl {
  /*float: left;*/
  /*width: 50%;*/
  flex: 1; /* grows and takes 50% of the parent's width */
}

.bg-img {
  background: url('https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/photos/000/755/75552.ngsversion.1422285553360.adapt.1900.1.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 50px 50px; /* appears small since you've set it this way */
  /*height: 100%; not necessary / both div's have the same height by default, height is dictated by the height of the "tallest" flex-item (.f1) */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fl">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <!--Background image should appear below, in the empty div-->
  <div class="fl bg-img"></div>
</div>
```